# unittest data from setUpClass to setUp

Tags: python, python-unittest

in unittest python library, I can use the `setUp` method for set variables prior to each test and `setUpclass` prior to all test.

How I can pass data from `setUpClass` to `setUp` ?

I try this :

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.a = 0

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = cls.a

    def test_hello01(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.a, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

but I get

```
NameError: global name 'cls' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within setUp(), you can directly access 'a' without the 'cls' notation, ie:

```
def setUp(self):
    print self.a   # should print 0
```

Comment: I think the idea is make a "local" copy of the class attribute in the object, so that if `self.a` is modified, `cls.a` keeps the original value for the next time.

Comment: Each test will reset self.a back to 0 (in his example)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the class of the object with the `__class__` attribute.

```
self.a = self.__class__.a
```